# conda does not update

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, virtualbox

Hi everybody I am new of Anaconda and VirtualBox,

- I installed VirtualBox on Windows 10.
- On the virtual machine, I installed Ubuntu 20.4.4
- Subsequently, I installed Anaconda 4.7.12

I tried to update my current Anaconda version using:

```
anaconda update anaconda
```

but the outcome is like that:

```
ioinfo@bioinfo:~$ conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.13.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

The Anaconda info returns this:

```
bioinfo@bioinfo:~$ conda info

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/bioinfo/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 2.7.16.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /home/bioinfo/anaconda2  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/bioinfo/anaconda2/pkgs
                          /home/bioinfo/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/bioinfo/anaconda2/envs
                          /home/bioinfo/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/2.7.16 Linux/5.13.0-52-generic ubuntu/20.04.4 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Anyone have an idea why conda can't update?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion by the CLI? `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I tried the suggested command activating the 'base' environment and also deactivating the base environment. However the result is always what I reported in this question.: current version: 4.7.12.

Comment: Does the following sequence work for you – `conda update conda` then `conda update anaconda`

Comment: This time I added conda-forge to the channels. I am working on several machines and I believed that conda-forge was in the channels list but not. So when I run again the command conda update conda many packages have been downloaded and the conda 4.7.12 has been explicitely removed. But when I run conda --version the outcomes is the same conda 4.7.12. So I followed the suggestion to run conda update anaconda. It installed, downgrade and remove something. But conda --version is still 4.7.12